# Amazon SQS - FIFO Queues - how to configure Deduplication Internal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I think Amazon SQS has default deduplication interval of 5 minutes.
I was looking for a way to tweak this interval, cannot find in Actions->Configure Queue option.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a configurable option.

The intention is to avoid duplicates that are a result of network issues and retries. A 5-minute interval would be sufficient to identify such accidental duplications.

If you wish to deduplicate data that is "intentionally" in the feed, then you would need to write your own code to detect this when processing the messages.